# Save and restore window position of a LibGDX application (LWJGL)

Tags: window, position, size, libgdx, lwjgl

I want to restore the position and size of my LibGDX application (*[LwjglApplication](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplication.html)*) window when started again.

I know that I can use *[LwjglApplicationConfiguration](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplicationConfiguration.java)* to set the position of the window before creating it as follows:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.x = lastX;
cfg.y = lasty;

LwjglApplication a = new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), cfg);
```

But how can I read the last position of the window before quitting? The user might have moved and resized the window while playing my game. How to save the data?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to use the LWJGL class `Display` ([Javadoc](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#getX())) with methods `getX()` and `getY()` as you can see here:

```
int x = Display.getX();
int y = Display.getY();
```